# Implicit cast to bool of basic_istream/ifstream/ofstream doesn't work in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, visual-studio-2013

The code below compiles in VS 2012 but not in VS 2013

```
std::ofstream stm;
if(stm != NULL)
{
}
```

In VS 2013 you get this compilation error:

> binary '!=' no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::ofstream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

I looked at the headers and in `<xiobase>` and I found the following:

**VS2012**

```
ios_base::operator void *() const;
```

**VS2013**

`operator void *() const` has been removed and the operator bool with explicit was added instead:

```
ios_base::explicit operator bool() const;
```

Now my questions:

1. I couldn't find any information about this change in the internet. Do you know if there is an official article about this change anywhere?
2. I have legacy code where if(stm != NULL) is used a lot. For unrelated reasons it's preferable not to change the code. Is there a way to make it compile in VS 2013 without changing it? I couldn't find any conditional compilation directives that could restore operator `void*` or remove `explicit` from operator bool().

PS: gcc 4.9.0 still has `operator void*() const`. So it will not have this problem.

**UPDATE:**

To make my legacy code compile I implemented the following overloads as it was suggested:

```
#include <xiosbase>

bool operator==(const std::basic_ios<char, char_traits<char>> &stm, int null_val)
{
    return static_cast<bool>(stm) == null_val;
}

bool operator==(int null_val, const std::basic_ios<char, char_traits<char>> &stm)
{
    return operator==(stm, null_val);
}

bool operator!=(int null_val, const std::basic_ios<char, char_traits<char>> &stm)
{
    return !operator==(stm, null_val);
}

bool operator!=(const std::basic_ios<char, char_traits<char>> &stm, int null_val)
{
    return !operator==(stm, null_val);
}
```

In my case the `char` value type was enough and the second parameter is int because something that is not NULL is not supported anyway.

Comment: Well that change is part of the C++11 specification, so it should be pretty easy to find articles on it. If nothing else by reading a draft specification.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool is a very useful article. It says that operator void *() "until C++11" and explicit operator bool() "since C++11". So it looks like it's a known change

Comment: I doubt GCC 4.9's libstdc++ has `operator void*` when compiling in C++11 mode. I can't find it in [the GCC 4.9 `ostream` header](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/branches/gcc-4_9-branch/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/ostream?revision=209304&view=markup), which contains `operator bool`...

Comment: @rubenvb Look at this demo http://goo.gl/yIHOXx

Comment: Huh, that looks erronous... C++11 `27.5.5.1` has no `operator void*() const` in `std::basic_ios`. But [VS2013 still has it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kby3a433.aspx), although they show an example where the address of the stream object is taken.

Comment: Also relevant is [this mailing list discussion](http://gcc.1065356.n5.nabble.com/PATCH-PR56193-Wrong-test-operator-for-basic-ios-in-C-11-td911582.html), and [this patch](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/branches/gcc-4_9-branch/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_ios.h?r1=195849&r2=195939) seems to the wrong way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of legacy code, you could probably add a custom `operator!=` (and `operator==`) function which takes the correct arguments:

```
bool operator!=(std::basic_ios const& ios, const void* ptr);
bool operator!=(const void* ptr, std::basic_ios const& ios);
```

Comment: Overloading operators for `std::` types, is that even allowed?

Comment: @MSalters We do it all the time when making an inserter/extractor (`operator<<()`/`operator>>()`). Why should it not be?

Comment: @0x499602D2: Because in that case, the overload includes one of your own types. That obviously can't collide with a `std::` provided overload.

Answer (score 6):

C++11 requires some boolean conversions to be explicit that used to be implicit. This is noted in Appendix C about compatibility with C++03:

> C.2.15 Clause 27: Input/output library [diff.cpp03.input.output]
>
> 27.7.2.1.3, 27.7.3.4, 27.5.5.4
>
> Change: Specify use of explicit in existing boolean conversion operators
>
> Rationale: Clarify intentions, avoid workarounds.
>
> Effect on original feature: Valid C++ 2003 code that relies on implicit boolean conversions will fail to compile with this International Standard. Such conversions occur in the following conditions:
>
> - passing a value to a function that takes an argument of type bool;
> - using operator== to compare to false or true;
> - returning a value from a function with a return type of bool;
> - initializing members of type bool via aggregate initialization;
> - initializing a const bool& which would bind to a temporary.

Comment: In MSVC 2015 `if(stm)` compiles, but `if(stm == true)` fails. How come only the second one qualifies as 'implicit boolean conversion'?   Could this be an MSVC bug?

Answer (score 0):

The operator is defined in section `27.5.5 Class template basic_ios`.

> 27.5.5.1 Overview
>
> `explicit operator bool() const;`

And then

> 27.5.5.4 basic_ios flags functions
>
> `explicit operator bool() const;`
>
> Returns: !fail().