# Implicit conversion of stream to bool

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Take this toy code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {

    std::ifstream is;
    // perform read
    // ...
    if (!is) // works
        std::cout << "fail";
    if( is == false)  // error C2678
        std::cout << "fail";

    return 0;
}
```

You'd get the following counter-intuitive results: `if(!is)` compiles, and `if(is==false)` gives

> error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand
>   operand of type 'std::ifstream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

(for VS2015 - similar errors in gcc and clang).

The standard says (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23236824/89706)):

> Valid C++ 2003 code that relies on implicit boolean conversions will
>   fail to compile with this International Standard. Such conversions
>   occur in the following conditions:
>
> - passing a value to a function that takes an argument of type bool;
> - using operator== to compare to false or true;
> - returning a value from a function with a return type of bool;
> - initializing members of type bool via aggregate initialization;
> - initializing a const bool& which would bind to a temporary.

As far as I can tell `if(is==false)` is explicitly required to fail, but how come `if(!is)` doesn't?  Doesn't it qualify as an 'implicit boolean conversion'?

Was this conversion-to-bool deliberately omitted from the cases listed in the standard?  Perhaps it's an unintentional omission?

---

Edit:
This code fails just as well:

```
int main() {

    std::ifstream is;
    // perform read
    // ...
    if (is) // works
        std::cout << "success";
    if( is == true)  // error C2678
        std::cout << "success";

    return 0;
}
```

And here the presence of operator!() is irrelevant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::ifstream`'s inherited `operator bool` is [marked `explicit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool):

> `explicit operator bool() const;`
>   (2) (since C++11)

What this means is that there is **no** implicit conversion to bool, i.e. all of those expressions fail:

```
bool result = is;    // fails
bool b = is == true; // fails
if (is == false);    // fails
while (is == false); // fails
```

If you wonder why `if (is)` and similar statements compile, that is because there are special rules for `if`, `while`, and the like for conversions: The `explicit` keyword is ignored!

```
if (is);                        // ok
while (is)                      // ok
bool b = static_cast<bool>(is); // ok
```

Note that the last case compiles because you are *explicitly* wanting a bool.

Technically, `!is` would work fine, as you explicitly *want* a bool, but `std::ifstream` has a inherited [`operator!`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!), so that operator is called instead of the default `operator!` which operates on bools:

```
if (!is);     // ok
bool b = !is; // ok
```

Comment: It could [potentially work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5f1f0d91368afc3) without the explicit `operator!`

Comment: I also think it could work just like `is && true` does

Comment: @Rakete1111 Thanks. Can you quote the standard on this?  Do you have any insight into *why* if/while clauses ignore the explicit keyword?  It certainly makes it more confusing (for me at least).

Comment: @OfekShilon look up [*contextual conversion to bool*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions). That is the context of the controlling expression of `if` and so on. Explicit operator bool is considered in those contexts.

Answer (score 4):

`!is` works because `std::basic_ios`, one of the base classes for the streams, has an [`operator!()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!) defined.

So this is not a conversion at all, it is a call to `is.operator!()`.

Comment: You're right, but this isn't the root cause. I've edited the question to reflect it: `if(is)` succeeds just as `if(!is)`

Comment: Yes, because `std::basic_ios` also has an `operator bool()` that complements the `operator!()`.

Comment: The operator is marked `explicit`, which is the source of the confusion. Turns out the explicit qualifier is ignored in this context

Comment: No, it's not. This is exactly the place where an `explicit operator bool()` is designed to work: "Certain language constructs require that an expression be converted to a Boolean value. An expression `e` appearing in such a context is said to be *contextually converted to bool* and is well-formed if and only if the declaration `bool t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t`"

Comment: `explicit` isn't mentioned there. Am I missing something?

Comment: The key here is `bool t(e);` which is an explicit conversion to `bool`. The guys writing the quoted phrase know that, and assume that we also have a holistic view of the standard - you have to read *all* of it and realize what parts affect other parts.